# jQuery: if value is true without user action

Tags: jquery

I want to show a div if the value of an input =='CP'.

Right now this is my code:

```
$(".register-type").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == 'CP'){
    $('.cp-show').show();
```

This works fine if they change the input, but if things get validated false and the page reloads, this input is still 'CP', but the div doesn't show...

Is there a way to correct this so that jquery checks if this is set on the page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for checking at load time.

```
var register = $(".register-type")[0];

function show_cp() {
    if(register.value == 'CP') {
      $('.cp-show').show();
    }
}

reg_type.change(show_cp);   // when the input changes
$(document).ready(show_cp); // when the page is loaded
```

Comment: Shorter version: `var chkVal=function(e){if ($(this).val()=='CP')$('.cp-show').show();} $('.register-type').change(chkVal).each(chkVal);`

Comment: This makes sense, but I'm having a little trouble. Can I limit the ready function to a particular div? Or must it be the document?

Answer (score 1):

Why not triggering it the first time..

```
$(".register-type")
    .change(function(){
        var value = this.value; // changeed the .val() since it is not needed here.
        if(value == 'CP'){
        $('.cp-show').show();
    })
    .trigger('change');
```

Comment: I've never seen `.trigger()` before?  Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: *`trigger()`: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.*. Nice idea, Gaby! +1

Comment: @Kevin, it is a jQuery method (more at http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). It calls (*triggers*) the event you provide for the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add to your 'document ready' function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(".register-type").val() == 'CP'){
        $('.cp-show').show();
    }
});
```